# Ratchet socket ws to wss

Tags: php, docker, websocket, wss, ratchet

I have two Docker containers. One is app running on https, other is a web socket one running on Ratchet library.

When I'm on a Mac I have no issues connecting from `https` to `ws`, and I presume it is because Docker is running on `127.0.0.1` so I suppose there are some special rules which allow it.

Switching to Win machine the problem arises because Docker is on `192.168.99.100` and now connecting `https` to `ws` no longer works because browser is expecting `https` to `wss` connection. Just switching endpoint to `wss://` instead of `ws://` obviously doesn't work out of the box as the connection handshake naturally times out.

My socket container is not running nginx nor apache, it is a simple Ratchet server which ultimately just exposes the port I told it on outside.

Are there some good resources on how to switch to `wss` because I could find none.

This is what I've tried:

```
$server = IoServer::factory(new HttpServer($wsServer), $config['port'], '0.0.0.0', [
    'local_cert'        => __DIR__ . '/../config/cert.pem',
    'allow_self_signed' => true,
    'verify_peer'       => false,
    'ciphers'           => 'TLSv1.2'
]);
```

This code doesn't error out, but nor does it enable `wss` endpoint because the same thing is happening. How can I proceed and make this work? Also I've read somewhere that wss self signed certificates are not allowed. Can I use a signed cert on socket container and have app container on self signed certificate or they both need to use the same one?

EDIT:

since Ratchet removed SSL a while ago, I added the code to the `IoServer::factory()`:

```
    public static function factory(MessageComponentInterface $component, $port = 80, $address = '0.0.0.0', array $sslContext = null) {
        $loop   = LoopFactory::create();
        $socket = new Reactor($address . ':' . $port, $loop);

        if (is_array($sslContext)) {
            $socket = new SecureReactor($socket, $loop, $sslContext);
        }

        return new static($component, $socket, $loop);
    }
```

But even without it, I tried it the other way also:

```
$server = new IoServer(new HttpServer($wsServer), new SecureServer($webSock, $loop, array(
        'local_cert'        => __DIR__ . '/../config/cert.pem',
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'verify_peer'       => false,
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up starting Ratchet as-is (normal `ws`) and doing a nginx proxy pass on app side:

```
   location /ws {
        resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
        set $backend "http://container_name:port";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass $backend;
     }
```

The resolver part ensures that nginx doesn't error out when you kill the container.