# Using Ratchet WebSockets in a Secure Environment is not working

Tags: ssl, websocket, ratchet

I am using Ratchet WebSocket in a Windows-based server project that is entirely working in an insecure environment. That is to say that when I navigate my browser to `http://www.example.com` and connect to the websocket server using `ws://` on port 8686 everything works spectacularly.

The server doesn't run through IIS - but instead is executed via php.exe in command prompt like this.

```text
php wsocket-server.php [...parameters...]
```

However, if run the Ratchet Server and try to connect from `https://www.example.com` using `wss://` the browser simply will not connect to the websocket server, despite the fact that the server starts up fine and the insecure site and connect via `ws://`

Now, I realize I need to utilize some additional code to include my SSL documentation. This is the relevant code I have in place:

```php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

$websocket_server = new WsServer();

if ($site_secure){
   //RUN WSS (SECURE) SERVER
    $options = [
        'local_cert'        => 'c:\inetpub\ssl\2c6fa1928847451c.crt',
        'local_pk'          => 'c:\inetpub\ssl\2c6fa1928847451c.key',
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'verify_peer'       => false
    ];
    
    $loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
    $websocket_server->enableKeepAlive($loop);
    $app = new HttpServer($websocket_server);

    $insecure_websockets = new \React\Socket\Server('0.0.0.0:'.$port, $loop);
    $secure_websockets = new \React\Socket\SecureServer($insecure_websockets , $loop, $options);
    $secure_websockets_server = new \Ratchet\Server\IoServer($app, $secure_websockets, $loop);

    $secure_websockets_server->run();
}else{    
   //RUN WS (INSECURE) SERVER
    $http_server = new HttpServer($websocket_server);
    $server = IoServer::factory($http_server, $port);
    $websocket->log ("Initializing ".(($site_secure) ? "Secure " : "Insecure ")."Server ($port)");
    $server->run();
}
```

## What I have tried

- I have ensured the correct ports are all open in the windows firewall.
- I have ensured nothing else is listening on the port using `netstat`
- I have tried using nginx, on a minimal level. I'd prefer to NOT use this method if possible, and was having some initial problems with it starting up so I did not dedicate 100% to it at this time. Ideally, I'd like to use Ratchet's native abilities.
- I have searched other similar posts both here and elsewhere, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61468663/ratchet-socket-ws-to-wss).
- I have tried a number of different ports, even the same 8686 as I use in the insecure connection

I am hoping someone can lend me an assist with an issue that has been driving me crazy for 2 weeks. At this point I feel like I'm just trying things to try them and I may be coding myself in circles.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not 100% sure, but right off the bat it looks like $site_secure is undefined. I hope this helps.

Edit: December 30th, 2023 10:32 PM EST:
Well maybe this can help you somehow. Here's what I wrote for myself months ago when I figured out needed to be done for me to get this working with Apache and CentOS 7. Maybe you can use some of the information.

"
All the lines below are the code for custom.conf. This is how to setup web sockets with Apache and CentOS 7 server with EasyApache installed. You will need the mod_proxy, mod_proxy_wstunnel, mod_ssl, and mod_http. This config file is required to get wss:// connections working for web sockets. You then would be able to connect by opening a TCP port for in, and out connections, and then setting up your websocket server to listen on that port for connections. Then in your javascript you connect with "wss://[ADDON DOMAIN]:1234/wss" with 1234 being your chosen TCP port, and "[ADDON DOMAIN]" being your domain name. How this works is the proxy pass listens for connections to /wss and then opens a proxy so you can recieve and send information on your TCP port. Make sure you have SSL installed, and that your webpage is using https:// .

```
#THE PATH TO THIS FILE IS: /etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/<CPANEL USERNAME>/<ADDON DOMAIN>.<SERVERS MAIN DOMAIN>/custom.conf
#HAVE TO UNCOMMENT "Include "/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/<CPANEL USERNAME>/<ADDON DOMAIN>.<SERVERS MAIN DOMAIN>/*.conf" IN THE <VirtualHost <SERVER IP HERE>:443> section of /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf  for this to work!

#August 19th, 2023 8:20 PM EST. CUSTOM CONFIG. Needed for Web Sockets

#Redirect all wss requests to the ws protocoal internally
ProxyPass /wss ws://127.0.0.1:<YOUR WEBSOCKETS PORT NUMBER HERE>/
ProxyPassReverse /wss ws://127.0.0.1:<YOUR WEBSOCKETS PORT NUMBER HERE>/"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: $site_secure is actually defined. I just failed to include that in the snippet I posted. Thanks for giving it a look over though.

Comment: It's probably something with your virtualhost equivalent? I use Apache, so I'm not sure how it works with Windows Server.

Comment: I added more to my answer. I hope this can help you.